# Perform left merge with missing integer data in right table, while preserving integer column types

Tags: python, pandas

I have tables with integer columns. I want to perform a left merge, where the right table does not have values for all keys. But I don't want the resulting table to have the int columns converted to float (which happens to represent NA, i.e., the missing keys in the right table).

Is this possible?

Comment: if you're gonna have nulls, you're gonna have floats